# PHP opentok SDK - startarchive returns a error

Tags: php, opentok

When I'm trying to call (via AJAX, during established session, with one Moderator publishing):

```
$openTok -> startArchive( $sessionId, "My Archive" );
```

I'm getting:

```
Fatal error: 
Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException' with message 'Client error response
[status code] 404
[reason phrase] Not Found
[url] https://api.opentok.com/v2/partner/44937XXX/archive' in F:\2 Workspace\5 Aptana\TokBox\vendor\guzzle\guzzle\src\Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException.php:43
Stack trace:

 #0 F:\2 Workspace\5 Aptana\TokBox\vendor\guzzle\guzzle\src\Guzzle\Http\Message\Request.php(145): Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException::factory(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest), Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\Response))
#1 [internal function]: Guzzle\Http\Message\Request::onRequestError(Object(Guzzle\Common\Event), 'request.error', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher))
#2 F:\2 Workspace\5 Aptana\TokBox\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher.php(164): call_user_func(Array, Object(Guzzle\Common\Event), 'request.error', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher))
#3 F:\2 Workspace\5 Apt in F:\2 Workspace\5 Aptana\TokBox\vendor\opentok\opentok\src\OpenTok\Util\Client.php on line 200
```

In addition, I've tried to run "*Archiving Sample App*", and Archiving is working there !

What am I doing wrong? Why I'm getting that "*Fatal error*" ?  :?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently problem was in trying to run my program from localhost.
Every other function was working correctly, except archivization, but when I have moved program to server, it started working properly.

Comment: For localhost on PHP, make sure you have enabled fopen in your .ini file so that PHP can send http requests: http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen